# Non-visible char in const char * as strtok() delimiter

Tags: string, split, newline, strtok

I had to split the payload of network data by the "new line" or "line feed" character (dec 10, hex 0x0A).
So i tried to use strtok() function with which i encountered several problems
when i wanted to make a const char string with the "new line" character.

Proto:

> ```
> `strtok(char * StringToSplit, const char * Delimiters)`
> ```

This made an invalid initializer:

> ```
> `const char delim[] = 10;`
> ```

This gave warning about making pointer from int without cast;
Allthough
       `printf("Delim: %x", delim)`

showed correct value of delim (0xa)
the app crashes when used in strtok().

> ```
> `const char * delim = 10;`
> ```

No warning or errors, printf("Delim: %x", delim) gave correct value
but strtok() didn't work (as i expected, though).

> ```
> `char delim = 10;`
> `(ofc strtok(..., &delim))`
> ```

This seemed to do the job but i still got a warning about passing a non const char ptr where a const char ptr was expected to strtok() function.

> ```
> `char delim[] = "#";`  
> `delim[0] = 10;`
> ```

Finally this seems to work without warnings.

> ```
> `char tmp[] = "#";`  
> `tmp[0] = 10;`  
> `const char *delim = tmp;`
> ```

Question is, what would be the simplest and most elegant way to pass such a non-visible character to the strtok() function?
To me it feels like this is just kludged code.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
const char *delim = "\n";
```

The second parameter needs to be a C string containing the delimiters. What you have in your various incarnations are lots of things that *aren't* C strings being incorrectly cast to C strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not kludged or inelegant, it's just got lots of bugs.

```
 const char delim[] = 10;
```

Why are you declaring an *array* here? This should be:

```
 const char delim = 10;
```

And then:

```
 char delim[] = "#";
```

Why are you declaring an array and setting it equal to a *string*? This shuld be:

```
 char delim = '#';
```